tqdm not working within another library, but working fine directly in Jupyter Notebook
In my Jupyter Notebook environment, everything works correctly with using tqdm and its progress bar directly. For example, the following code:
for i in tqdm(range(100000)):
    pass

is correctly displayed:

But when I use some other libraries that themselves call tqdm internally, like Node2Vec in the following code:
from node2vec import Node2Vec

node2vec = Node2Vec(
    G, dimensions=64, walk_length=100,
    num_walks=2000, workers=4, seed=59, quiet=False
)

Then it is not displayed and just some spaces are added in the outputs:

I don't know why it's happening; can someone explain please?

I know a while ago this was an issue because of how nested the tqdm was wrapped in the use and not connected to the notebook, see here. You don't show how you tried with Pandas? It may that you are using these libraries in ways expected to be in Python more directly because they are long running in general & Jupyter is meant to be interactive.

@Wayne my bad about pandas, it is however working with tqdm.pandas(). Edited the question.
